# bcp export command adds an extra column on 2 out of 400 records

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am using bcp command to export a table out as a tab delimited text file.  Out of about 400 records, 2 records have an extra column and it's messing up those rows.

Here is the tsql code i've used to export.

```
DECLARE @bcpCommand varchar(2000)
DECLARE @FileName varchar(80)

 SET @FileName = 'c:\data\output.txt'
 SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM  mytable" queryout "' 
 SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FileName + '" -T -c -S Localhost -f c:\format\myTable.fmt '
      
 EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

All other recs are fine.  just these two.  There is an extra tab between the city field (#5) and the state field (#6).

Here is the format file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="60" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="80" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="60" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="6" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="12" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="PlanTo" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="DESCRIPTION" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ADDRESS1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="ADDRESS2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="CITY" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="STATE" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="ZIPCODE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Status" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="PriceList" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="Broker" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Can you help?

Comment: Is there any chance that the data in the colums are dirty? like a hidden tab at the end? Try clensing the data perhaps before running bcp over it?

Comment: My guess? Those two rows in the database table have an embedded tab character, which would explain why it doesn't happen in the other rows. Did you check the data?

Comment: More likely that some of the data itself actually contains tab characters and that is what is messing up your "tab delimited format." The [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) is great for doing server-to-server transfers of native format data, but it's generally quite loathsome for anything else. Amongst other things, it doesn't know how to escape quotes, linebreaks or field delimiters so as to be able to read or generate [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)-compliant files. Have you tried PowerShell's `Export-Csv` cmdlet instead?

Comment: instead of SELECT * as argument to BCP use select col1, col2... etc, and do a REPLACE(colWithTab, CHAR(9), '') for those columns where problem occurs. And yeah, feel free to stop using BCP altogether.

Comment: wow.  I did "select * from myTable where (rtrim(city) like '%' + char(9) + '%')" and those two records got selected!  There is a tab within the field!  Thank you everyone for your answers/comments!!!